# How to pass a json data to my html file from my Python .py file?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am currently trying to integrate this free to use 3rd Party API into my website. I am using Python which uses flask so I will be using render templates so how do I pass this data through my to my template?

below is the method within my .py class which also has requests packaged installed. NOTE: I have used an invalid API key just for security measures.

```
@app.route('/Api', methods=['POST'])
def index():

    # BBC news api 
    main_url = " https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=123"

    # fetching data in json format 
    open_bbc_page = requests.get(main_url).json() 

    # getting all articles in a string article 
    article = open_bbc_page["articles"] 

    # empty list which will  
    # contain all trending news 
    results = [] 

    for ar in article: 
        results.append(ar["title"]) 

    for i in range(len(results)): 

        # printing all trending news 
        print(i + 1, results[i])                  

return render_template('home_page.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Also how do I then display this in my html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render_template` method takes `**context` parameters after the first parameter, which are variables that are to be made available in the context of the template. For example,

```
return render_template('home_page.html', results=results)
```

You can parse the response you receive from the requests however you'd like.

If you're returning a list, you can iterate through the list in the template with something like:

```
{% for result in results %}
    <p>{{result}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi , thank for the response. I currently new to python. i've tried this in my .py return render_template('home_page.html', display=results) however it does not pass anything to html using <p>{{display}}</p>

Comment: thanks, I have tried your example. I have pasted this loop into my html page however it does not return anything? could there be something wrong with my python code?

Comment: I can now confirm that it was my python code that was the issue, however this does answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `articles` variable into your template.

```
return render_template('home_page.html, articles = articles )’
```

Then run your for loops in your template. Ex:

```
 {%for ar in articles%}

Do stuff

{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Hi, Wes the question above as the same similar answer however I have tried your way still the same issue. Displaying nothing? would it be my python code?